# What WP slideshow plugin is being used on this page?

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

I am trying to find out which plugin they are using on this page for the slideshow content - ive tried reading the code but its not giving me any indication on what it is specific.

http://www.rd.com/slideshows/15-secrets-the-emergency-room-staff-wont-tell-you/?trkid=outbrain-all#slideshow=slide15

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a WordPress plugin.  The source code seems to indicate they created this jQuery plugin themselves.  (The objects for the slideshow are namespaced with `rd`, which is the domain name, aka Reader's Digest).

They *are* using the jQuery hashchange event plugin to help control state with the forward and back buttons.  (See more here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Comment: The only problem i have with finding something similar is trying to do a search for slideshow brings up infinite photo galleries, and then if i try to do a search for "top 10" plugins like using it to list a top 10 features of somethign - it brings me lists of top 10 lists of plugins heh